# grep to ignore patterns

Tags: grep

I am extracting URLs from a website using cURL as below.

```
curl www.somesite.com | grep "<a href=.*title=" > new.txt
```

My new.txt file is as below.

```
<a href="http://website1.com" title="something">
<a href="http://website1.com" information="something" title="something">
<a href="http://website2.com" title="some_other_thing">
<a href="http://website2.com" information="something" title="something">
<a href="http://websitenotneeded.com" title="something NOTNEEDED">
```

However, I need to extract only the below information.

```
<a href="http://website1.com" title="something">
<a href="http://website2.com" information="something" title="something">
```

I am trying to ignore the `<a href` which have **information** in them and whose title end with **NOTNEEDED**.

How can I modify my grep statement?

Comment: Is the output you're showing here correct? The text describing it doesn't make sense along with this example.

Comment: Aren't you looking for `curl www.somesite.com | grep "<a href=.*title=" | grep -v NOTNEEDED > new.txt`?

Comment: @terdon, exactly that was what I was looking for. I can accept it as an answer if you post it.

Comment: Ramesh, it's basically @slm's answer. I have just edited it so you can accept it.

Comment: oh yeah, I did not realize pipe was this powerful. I have accepted it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not fully following your example + the description but it sounds like what you want is this:

```
$ grep -v "<a href=.*title=.*NOTNEEDED" sample.txt 
<a href="http://website1.com" title="something">
<a href="http://website1.com" information="something" title="something">
<a href="http://website2.com" title="some_other_thing">
<a href="http://website2.com" information="something" title="something">
```

So for your example:

```
$ curl www.example.com | grep -v "<a href=.*title=" | grep -v NOTNEEDED > new.txt
```

Comment: I have a class in the <a href section. Basically, I do not want that in my output.

Answer (score 12):

The [grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) man page says:

```
-v, --invert-match
    Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines. (-v is specified by POSIX .)
```

You can use regular expressions for multiple inversions:

```
grep -v 'red\|green\|blue'
```

or

```
grep -v red | grep -v green | grep -v blue
```